# how to change value of 'select' manually after rendering the component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, material-ui

I have set the value of Select to local state variable. child component updates that state change. but the drop down won't be able to change the selected value.
Please can someone check the below code and correct me. 
Thank you

Parent Component

```
class EditVehicle extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            values: {
                vehicleOwner: '',
            },

        }
    }
    setVehicleOwner = (owner) => {
        console.log(owner);
        this.setState({ vehicleOwner: owner._id });

    };
    render() {
        const { values } = this.state;
        return (
            ......
            <FormControl className={classes.formControl} >
                <Select
                    value={this.state.values.vehicleOwner}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    inputProps={{
                        name: 'vehicleOwner',
                        id: 'vehicleOwner',
                    }}>
                    {this.props.vehicleOwnersList && this.props.vehicleOwnersList.map((owner, index) => (
                        <MenuItem value={owner._id} key={index}>{owner.firstName} {owner.lastName}</MenuItem>
                    ))}
                </Select>
                <Tooltip title="New Vehicle Owner">
                    <IconButton className={classes.button} aria-label="New Vehicle Owner" color="primary" onClick={this.handleOpenOwnerCreateModal}>
                        <AddIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                </Tooltip>
            </FormControl>
            ......
            <Modal
                aria-labelledby="simple-modal-title"
                aria-describedby="simple-modal-description"
                open={this.state.openOwnerCreateModal}
                className={classes.modal}
                onClose={this.handleCloseOwnerCreateModal}>
                <NewVehicleOwnerModal
                    set={this.setVehicleOwner}
                    selected={null}
                    action={this.handleCloseOwnerCreateModal} />
            </Modal>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the code for the `this.handleChange` method?

Comment: handleChange = name => value => {
        this.setState({
            [name]: value,
        });
    };